# JavaScript: How to reference user control inside content page?

Tags: javascript

This is structure I have:

Master page -> Content page -> User control -> Telerik grid with its context menu, hidden field.

This means: Master page contains content page, content page contains user control, user control contains Telerik grid with its context menu and hidden field.

I open popup window by clicking option in Telerik grid's context menu. After I choose some option in combo box in that popup window I press OK and close it. But I don't know how to reference opener that should be user control with Telerik grid and hidden field. I want to set hidden field to some value.

This is JavaScript code I use:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ReturnValue() {
        var choice = document.getElementById("DropDownList1").value;
        if ((window.opener != null) && (!window.opener.closed)) {
            window.opener.document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = choice;
        }
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

But, it fails on this line because opener is master page:

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("HiddenField1").value = choice;
```

So, how can I make it work?

Comment: This is ASP.NET. I mean there's a content page inside master page.

Comment: Excuse me. I don't understand. I just need to set the value of hidden field inside of user control.

Comment: I have JavaScript function in popup window where from I should set the value of hidden field that is placed in user control inside content page.

Comment: I don't have any <iframe>.

Comment: Does anybody know how to make this work?